# jQuery - How do I replace the input value on keyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I enter some numbers and then select the first `input` and start typing new numbers, the new number doesn't replace the old `value`. How do I set up the code to follow the `keydown` function while also replacing the old value with the new one?

```js
// jQuery
$(".code-input").on("keyup", function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $(this)
      .next()
      .focus();
  }
});
$(".code-input").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).val() == "") {
    $(this)
      .prev("input")
      .focus();
  }
});
$(".code-input").on("paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text");
  var textArray = text.split("");

  $(".code-input").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).val(textArray[index]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode1">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode2">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode3">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode4">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode5">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode6">
```

Comment: You can use "select()" command after "focus()" to select current text, then old value will replace whit new one

Comment: You start by saying 'if I enter some numbers and then select the first `input`' ... where are you entering the original numbers? are you basically trying to make text boxes that only allow one number as input and replace an old number if it's there?

Comment: @Katie.Sun Yes that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the same event instead of both keyup and keydown like so:

```js
// jQuery
$(".code-input").on("keyup", function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).val() == "") {
    $(this)
      .prev("input")
      .select();
  } else if ($(this).val()) {
    $(this)
      .next()
      .select();
  }
});
$(".code-input").on("paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text");
  var textArray = text.split("");

  $(".code-input").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).val(textArray[index]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode1">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode2">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode3">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode4">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode5">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode6">
```

That way, you're not fighting with trying to change focus for both keyup/keydown events.

Comment: If I enter some digits, then use my cursor to select a previous input and hit `shift`, it skips to the next input. How do I have it so that if I manually change the value of a character already entered, it only proceeds using `.next()` when a change is made, or keycode 32 (spacebar) or 9 (tab) are entered?

Answer (score 0):

If you automagically select the text in the boxes when the user focuses on it, whatever they type next will replace what's there. Try adding this event to your code:

```
$(".code-input").on("focus", function(e) {
      $(this).select();
});
```

Alternatively, you could just automatically select the input when the user does a `keydown` on it, like so:

```
$(".code-input").on("keydown", function(e) {
     $(this).select();
        if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).val() == "") {
          $(this)
            .prev("input")
            .focus();
        }
 });
```

Comment: This is nice. However I am running into a problem when I use special characters. Using the shift key after I select and focus an input skips ahead.

Comment: What would you prefer happens? (also if you remove what I added that would still happen)

Comment: Well I only want the space bar or tab to move to the next input

Comment: @KyleUnderhill then in the part of your code where you call `next()`, you need to use the same `(e.which == 8 || e.which == 46)` (assuming that's what those key codes are)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...
add

```
$('.code-input').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

```js
$(".code-input").on("keyup", function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $(this)
      .next()
      .focus();
  }
});
$(".code-input").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if ((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).val() == "") {
    $(this)
      .prev("input")
      .focus();
  }
});
$(".code-input").on("paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text");
  var textArray = text.split("");

  $(".code-input").each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).val(textArray[index]);
  });
});
$('.code-input').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode1">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode2">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode3">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode4">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode5">
<input type="text" class="code-input" maxlength="1" name="verifyCode6">
```